# How to pass a value from a JPanel to a JFrame in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have the following method in my JPanel:

```
public void detectionTime(){
      detectStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long detectDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - detectStartTime;
      performance.lblDetectTime.setText(detectDuration + "ms");
  }
```

I want to print or output the detectDuration variable in a label i.e. lblDetectTime in a JFrame. I have created an instance of the JFrame as "performance" and I have also created an instance of the JPanel into the JFrame in order to access the method.

Answer (score 0):

Why pass, when you can directly set it.............

If still you want to pass it... then **change the return type of detectionTime() method in JPanel.**

```
public String detectionTime(){

detectStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long detectDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - detectStartTime;
return detectDuration + "ms";

 }
```

**Edited Again:**

Do this from class that extends the JFrame (ie your container)

`IblDetectTime.setText(MyPanel.detectionTime());`

Comment: I need to set the variable lblDetectTime in the JFrame to a value of detectDuration of the JPanel.

Comment: ya offcourse thats what it does...   `IblDetectTime = MyPanel.detectionTime();`

Comment: It has given me an incompatible types error. JLabel is incompantible with String. I tried using lblDetectTime.setText(detection.detectionTime()); but it doe not work. "detection" is an instance of the JPanel

Comment: I have edited my answer, see it again.. See the Edited Again: IblDetectTime.setText(MyPanel.detectionTime());

Comment: how do I call MyPanel into JFrame. I tried to create an instance of it as can be seen in my last comment i.e. MyPanel detection; If I just write MyPanel as it is, it gives me that a non static method detectionTime() can not be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Where are you creating MyPanel instance, i hope not in its main() or any static method. As static methods cannot access any non-static method or variable..and here detectionTime() is NON-STATIC

Comment: I am creating a JPanel instance in the JFrame class so that I can use the methods in the JPanel.

Comment: The JPanel and the JFrame are in separate classes using NetBeans.

Comment: There are no errors or warnings while using your example, but the label lblDetectTime does not update as the detectionTime() method return the results.